what is the difference between root.manager.current and app.root.current?
So, I'm new to using Kivy.
I saw some kivy tutorial abt how to change/switch screen. But, some use : on_release: root.manager.current and some use on_release: app.root.current. What's the difference between those two? How to decide which one to use?

The app.root.current is appropriate if the root of the app (the Widget returned by the build() method) is the ScreenManager you are trying to manage.
The root.manager.current is appropriate when the root of the kv rule that contains that expression is a Screen of the ScreenManager you are trying to manage.
See the documentation.
